# Rewrite $q\in Q$ using support function, for $Q$ convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $Q\subseteq \mathbb{R}^K$ be a convex closed set.

I would like your help to show or find the right reference in the literature for the steps below where I use the support function of $Q$ to represent the condition $q\in Q$. My questions are highlighted with number [1],[2] below.

In what follows I denote by $h(Q,b)$ the support function of $Q$ evaluated at $b\in \mathbb{R}^K$. I denote by $\mathbb{B}^K$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^K$, i.e., the set of $b\in \mathbb{R}^K$ such that $b^Tb\leq 1$. I denote by $\mathbb{S}^K$ the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^K$, i.e., the set of $b\in \mathbb{R}^K$ such that $b^Tb= 1$

$$
q\in Q 
$$
$$
\Updownarrow \text{[1] Which Theorem/property am I using here?}
$$
$$
b^T q - h(Q,b)\leq 0 \text{ }\forall b \in \mathbb{R}^K
$$
$$
\Updownarrow \text{Given that the above holds also for $b=0_{K\times 1}$}
$$
$$
\max_{b\in \mathbb{R}^K}[b^T q - h(Q,b)]=0 
$$
$$
\Updownarrow \text{By positive homogeneity of $h$, I divide both sides by $||q||$ and can focus only on $b$ s.t. $b'b=1$}
$$
$$
\max_{b\in \mathbb{S}^K}[b^T q - h(Q,b)]=0 
$$
$$
\Updownarrow \text{[2] Which Theorem/property am I using here?}
$$
$$
\max_{b\in \mathbb{B}^K}[b^T q - h(Q,b)]=0 
$$
$$
\Updownarrow \text{$Q$ closed implies $\sup=\max$}
$$
$$
\max_{b\in \mathbb{B}^K}[b^T q - \max_{\tilde{q}\in Q} b^T\tilde{q}]=0 
$$

Comment: If $h(Q,b) = \sup_{q \in Q} b^Tq$, then doesn't [1] just follow by definition?

Comment: Thanks. Definition of what? Maybe my notation is unclear. In [1] I'm asking why $q\in Q$ is equivalent ("$\Leftrightarrow$") to $b^T q - h(Q,b)\leq 0$ $\forall b \in \mathbb{R}^K$?

Comment: The definition of $h(Q,b)$. I understand what you are asking in [1].

Comment: I see, thanks. Could you help for the other two questions? Why I can just focus on the unit sphere or unit ball?